# Connection string in c# wpf

Tags: c#, database, wpf, tetris

i'm making a tetris game for one of my projects and one of my many problems start with making a connection string. I'm planning on making a login database through microsoft access but it's proving to be quite difficult.

```
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;


namespace Tetris
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for Page1.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class Page1 : Page
    {
        public Page1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void TextBox_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=Database1.accdb");

            

            if (pass.Password != "" && user.Text != "") 
            {
                if (pass.Password == "test" && user.Text == "user")
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Successful", "Valid");
                }
            }
        }

        private void Submit_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }

    internal class OleDbConnection
    {
        public OleDbConnection(string v)
        {
            V = v;
        }

        public string V { get; }
    }
}
```

This is the code so far on visual studio 2019,where my teacher attempted to do it but got stuck herself

Comment: Sorry, but I don't think someone is able to help you without a detailed description what you want to achieve, what exact problem you are facing and what you've already tried to solve it.

Comment: What do you intend doing with the database?  It seems an odd exercise since ms access security is unique.  Access is also somewhat fragile. If you want to save data for a specific user then why not just serialise data to user's appdata? If you wanted to share scores then a local database is not a great choice. Why not SQLite?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly you want to set up a connection with access database.

I have actually had a problem with connection string with the Microsoft access before.

The problem I had is that the Microsoft Access Database Engine was in a language and the office I had was in other language so I had to reinstall the office to be the same language as the Database Engine.

add `using System.Data.OleDb;` import the `OleDbConnection class` to your file (you might need to add a Reference.

this is the documentation for this class   [OleDbConnection Documintation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.oledb.oledbconnection?view=dotnet-plat-ext-7.0).

you also need to check if you have Microsoft access 2007(`Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0` ), make sure that the access file your connection string is pointing to the correct location of your database file.

after that follow this instruction [Connect to data in access database](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/data-tools/connect-to-data-in-an-access-database-windows-forms?view=vs-2022).